# Mifare Ultralight C authentication

Tags: android, authentication, nfc, mifare

I am working with NFC tags (Mifare Ultralight C) but I have problems with authentication.

If I understand correctly on page 42 should be information about restricted pages. There is value 04d83460 so pages 4+ should require authentication?

On page 43 value is 4a402b80. Why there is such a value and what that means?

I can write and read to pages 4-40 but if I try to write pages 41+ nothing happens.

**EDIT:**

```
MifareUltralight mifare = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
        if(mifare == null){
            Log.e(LOG, "mifare null");
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG, "mifare not null");
            switch(mifare.getType()){
            case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT:
                Log.e(LOG, "ultralight");
                break;
            case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT_C:
                Log.e(LOG, "ultralight c");
                break;
            case MifareUltralight.TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                Log.e(LOG, "type unknown");
                break;
            }
        }


        try {
            mifare.connect();
            mifare.writePage(39, new byte[]{0x10, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02});

            Log.e(LOG, "read");

            byte[] resp = mifare.readPages(40);

            for(byte b : resp){
                Log.e(LOG, "resp: " + b);
            }



            mifare.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Have you double checked that you really read those values from pages 42 and 43? Have you checked that reading works by reading pages 0 and 1 and comparing them to the tags UID? Regarding writing: What's the state of the lock bits?

Comment: @MichaelRoland Yes I checked that, its from pages 42 and 43. Reading works ok, I checked that also by using NFC TagInfo app. Page 2(lock bits) is 6f48000 so it's not a problem. Page 40 is 8000000 so it's also not a problem.

Comment: Could you show how you read those values from the tag?

Comment: @MichaelRoland see edit. I checked that with NFC TagInfo android app so I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: The line `byte[] resp = mifare.readPages(40);` (i.e. that you read four pages starting from page 40 with potentical roll-over to page 0) and the fact that `04d83460` looks like the start of a UID (and thus like a valid content for page 0, including a valid BCC0) makes me even more convinced that your tag is not MF Ultralight C but some other type of tag (e.g. NTAG203) that does not have those pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag does not seem to be a MIFARE Ultralight C tag. Instead it seems that this is a tag with 42 pages (this could be, for instance an NTAG203).

The first indication for this is the value that you read from page 42: `04d83460`. This looks like the start of the UID including BCC0. `0x04` looks like the manufacturer ID of NXP. Moreover, the value `0x60` would be a valid BCC0 for `0x88` (cascade tag) XOR `0x04` XOR `0xD8` XOR `0x34`. Therefore, this could be a valid value of page 0.

The second indication for this is the way how you read those pages:

```
byte[] resp = mifare.readPages(40);
```

With this line you read four pages starting from page 40. If the memory area is smaller than 44 pages, this command will roll over to the start of the memory area. Hence, if the memory area consists of 42 pages, this command will return pages 40, 41, 0, and 1. Consequently, what you interpret as pages 42 and 43 are actually pages 0 and 1.

The only strange thing about this is that your page 2 contains the value `6f480000`. If page 1 contained `4a402b80` (the remaining UID), then the first byte of page 2 (BCC1) should be `0x4A` XOR `0x40` XOR `0x2B` XOR `0x80` = `0xA1` and *not* `0x6F`.